# Solve following pde (D^2+2DD'+D'^2-2D-2D')Z=SIN(X+2Y).

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

i am trying to solve (D^2+2DD'+D'^2-2D-2D')Z=SIN(X+2Y).
if first factorise (D^2+2DD'+D'^2-2D-2D') into (D+D')(D+D'-2) and then i use D+mD'
and put y=c-mx.(whre m=-1) then i get -cos(2y+2x)/4(D+D'-2) ,after that i dont know how to solve it .

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

From

$$
\left(\partial_x+\partial_y\right)\left(\partial_x+\partial_y-2\right)u = \sin(x+2y)
$$

calling

$$
U = \left(\partial_x+\partial_y-2\right)u
$$

we have

$$
\left(\partial_x+\partial_y\right)U = \sin(x+2y)
$$

now solving for $U$ we have

$$
U(x,y) = \phi(y-x)-\frac 13\cos(x+2y)
$$

and finally

$$
\left(\partial_x+\partial_y-2\right)u = \phi(y-x)-\frac 13\cos(x+2y)
$$

etc.